# Adding instance attribute value to other instance's attribute, where is my mistake?

Tags: python-3.x, class, attributes, instance

I have tried to find an explanation of why the following...

```
class First():
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value + object_second.value_2

class Second():
    def __init__(self):
        self.value_2 = 0

    def change_value_2(self):
        self.value_2 = 10


object_second = Second()
object_first = First(10)

print(object_first.value)
object_second.change_value_2()
print(object_first.value)
```

...returns:

```
10
10
```

And not, what I expected:

```
10
20
```

Does the first instance's attribute not get updated automatically when the second instance's attribute gets updated, even though the first instance's attribute's value is dependent on the latter?

Answer (score 0):

Just have a look at the code you have written. you first create the `Second` object which will create it with `value2` as `0`. you then create the `first` object which will assign to its attribute `value` the value that you passed in (10) and the value of `value2` of `second` which is `0`. `10 + 0 = 10` so the result 10 is assigned to `value` of `first`. When you change `value2` later that doesnt affect `first` as it already evaluated and added them. changeing `value2` later will have no effect on `value`

So your value in first will only be evaluated when first is created. it wont update when you change second. you can see this if you create another first object after you change second. the additional first object will have its value as 20 as it was created after second had its value set to 10

```
class First():
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value + object_second.value_2

class Second():
    def __init__(self):
        self.value_2 = 0

    def change_value_2(self):
        self.value_2 = 10


object_second = Second()
object_first = First(10)

print(object_first.value)
object_second.change_value_2()
print(object_first.value)
object_first2 = First(10)
print(object_first2.value)
```

**OUTPUT**

```
10
10
20
```

Also you should never write object instances directly in your class. If your class requires the object instance then you should pass it in as part of the call to create.

Comment: Thank you! I will rewrite and not use object instances in my classes. I will create methods and call them instead as needed instead. Greatly appreciated!